# MRTK 2.7.3 - Outline Shader is not visible on HoloLens

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, mrtk

I saw the scene `OutlineExamples` in the MRTK examples package and recreated it in my own project.

The outlining works if I stay in unity in play mode. But if I deploy it on the HoloLens the object does not get a outline effect.

The `OutlineExamples` scene from the `MRTKHub-project` works as excpected on the HoloLens!

So I guess I missed something in my own project, but I cant find it. I compared the setup multiple times, but cant find a difference. And I also used the simplest object (the cube) from the example scene.

**Setup for the cube**

[image: Screenshot]

(the screenshot shows on the left side my project and on the right side the mrtkhub-project):

- Mesh Filter (standard)
- Mesh Renderer (standard)
- Box Collider (standard)
- MeshOutline with the Material "OutlineOrange" or "OutlineGreen" (added)
- Object Manipulator (added)
- Constraint Manager (added)

The only thing that I had to setup after adding the as "added" marked compenents, was the material for the `MeshOutline` component.

Is there something else someone has to setup to see the outline shader on the HoloLens?

**My Setup:**

- Unity 2020.3.30
- MRTK 2.7.3
- Visual Studio 2019

**What else did I check?**

The XR Plug-in Management is set up the same way

[image: Screenshot]

**--EDIT**

I noticed something strange and I guess this will help someone who knows more about shader!

I launched my application on the HoloLens, grabbed the cube and put it in front of a window in my room. While placing the cube in front of the window, I saw the outline! But as soon as I move it outside the window area, the outline disappears! Another aspect is that I'm using the spatial mapping from MRTK. That means that the window does not get meshed, only the walls. And I guess the walls have their own shader on it, right?

So the spatial mesh shader and the outline shader "dont like each other". Is this possible?

Comment: `So the spatial mesh shader and the outline shader "dont like each other". Is this possible?` -> yes, absolutely! It depends on the rendering order. Maybe the wall shader is rendered on top of the outline. Not sure how MRTK does the outline but often you go like 1) render the object slightly bigger in the target outline color 2) render the object normal on top of it => looks like an outline around the object ... possible that the shader for your spatial mapping comes rendered after the first pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user derHugo gave me a hint that led to the solution! I went to the material, that I use on the cube and changed the property `Render Queue Override` under `Advanced Options` to a higher value than the material `MRTK_Occlusion`, which is used for the spatial mapping, has.